# Unity3d - Raycast Needs to Check Layer Before Instantiate

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, raycasting

I'm making a game where the player touches the screen and an object instantiates . However, I only want the object to instantiate if the Raycast hits an object that is on a specific layer (or of a specific tag if that is easier). I can get the ray to cast out and instantiate a prefab where I'd like it, but when I add in the section of checking for the layer, it sends me an error (NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object). This seems like such a simple thing but I can't get it to work. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
var box : Transform;



function Update ()
{

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
if(roomController.noMore == false){
var hit : RaycastHit;
var mousePos : Vector3 = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = 9;
var worldPos : Vector3 = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
Debug.Log("Mouse pos: " + mousePos + " World Pos: " + worldPos + " Near Clip Plane: " + camera.nearClipPlane);

if(hit.collider.gameObject.layer == "Ground" && HierarchyType.collider != null){
clone = Instantiate(box, worldPos, Quaternion.identity);
noMore = true;
Destroy(this);
}

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Physics.Raycast.

```
var hit : RaycastHit;
if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), hit))
{
    if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Water"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Instantiate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but when I add in the section of checking for the layer, it sends me
>   an error (NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object).

This is probably because actually you are not casting any ray and checking that an hit actually occurred( avoid the relative collider field could be null).

I suggest you to have a look at [Physics.RayCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) overloads, it could be significant more efficient to specify the layer (through `LayerMask`) while casting instead of filtering the results later.